# Cant import OpenCV module in android studio

Tags: android, opencv

I've been trying to import Open CV module to android studio exactly as many tutorials online told me to but it wont work. I googled the issue a bit and found a solution to choose the sdk folder as the directory and not java but even that dosent work.Im using Android Studio v4.0.1 and the latest version of OpenCV. Help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all make sure your sdk folder in your downloaded opencv sdk contains a build.gradle file. If your downloaded sdk doesn't have build.gradle try another version of opencv sdk, Unless you have to select java folder in the opencv sdk and after that copy jni files into your project tree.
The easiest way to import OpenCV sdk into your project is as follow:

1. Create an Android Project
2. File -> New -> Import Module -> path to OpenCV/sdk/   -not java folder! (opencv 4+)
3. File -> Project Structure -> add OpenCV as 'Module Dependency' of 'app'
4. Clean Project
5. Done! no need to copy jni libs and other things.

Comment: Sorry mods, but I have to thank this individual for giving me a solution that was as straightforward as I knew it should have been. So many wild goose chases before I found this post. Thank you!

Comment: Been wandering all over the net trying to find why people say,  OpenCV/sdk/java but that doesn't work for me. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks dadash. that's a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Importing opencv to androidstudio

->First download opencv from https://opencv.org/releases/
for your current using android studio version,and extract it.
->open android studio create new project if project is already
exist follow the below.
->in android studio choose option in MENU->File->Import
Module here please select the your opencv-android directory
till sdk selection
eg:("E:\stardev\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk") and
then finish, if your downloaded same version it's good to go
else change the build.gradle setting from opencv build.gradle
and sync.
->after this to add as a dependency in android studio
Choose
Menu->File->Project Structure->dependencies,
select app from tab and add(+ icon) from menu select module
dependency and select sdk from here.
->to test goto your project activity and
(import org.opencv.core.Core)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Arctic fox and still facing this issue, This Solution worked for me.

If your next and/or finish buttons is still not clickable after adding the right path

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68738767/12052997