# OpenCV Android Studio module importing issue

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-studio-arctic-fox

I`m trying to import OpenCV to android studio project, but have inactive "next" and "finish" button. So i cant finish OpenCV importing.
Using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 and tried different version of OpenCV(4.5.3, 3.4.1, 3.4.15 etc.)
There are screenshots of issue [Next and Finish disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd9SM.png)
[Next and Finish disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6vo.png)

**Edit:** Tried Android studio 4.2.2 - and it fix my problem. But i still dont know how to use it in Arctic Fox

Comment: use this dependency for importing opencv: implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:3.4.1'  reference from "https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android"

Comment: Yes, it do the trick. But there max version 4.3.0 and i want to use 4.5.3

Comment: what task do you want to perform with  version 4.5.3 that can not be done with 3.4.1?

Comment: This is customer requirement. As i mentioned in "Edit", i already find way to import OpenCV 4.5.3 by using AS 4.2.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### This Bug is in Android studio Arctic Fox

This issue is not about only `OpenCV` module, ***This is happening with all library modules.***

Many people are posted this issue on `issuetracker` but nobody get solution from `Android studio` team side.
here is some links of that issues posted on `issuetracker`.
[Link 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195336461) ,
[Link 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195849585) ,
[Link 3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195598564) ,
[Link 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196100679) ,
[Link 5](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195318441) ,
[Link 6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191209456) ,
[Link 7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340090)

#### So here is Temporary Workaround

1. copy `sdk` folder in your project directory
2. Add below line in `settings.gradle`

   `include ':sdk'`
3. click `sync now`
4. Done

##### If you get below error (I got this error while solving this issue)

> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

add below dependency in root level `build.gradle` and click `sync now`

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21" // add this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fixed with these steps

1. Copy the sdk folder from open cv and paste it in the project
2. Add this line **include ':sdk'** in settings.gradle
3. Then add this  line **implementation project(path: ':sdk')** inside the build.gradle (module )